# Mysql - How to sum over some amount based on date?

Tags: mysql, date, sum

I have a table as follows

```
+------+------------+-------+
| ID   | orderdate  | apple |
+------+------------+-------+
| 1005 | 2015-05-05 |     2 |
| 1005 | 2015-05-06 |     0 |
| 1006 | 2011-05-06 |     3 |
| 1006 | 2011-10-06 |     3 |
+------+------------+-------+
```

and I would like to sum the apple over orderdate to see the accumulative toatal amount of apple an ID bought.
for example, for the ID 1006, the person bought 3 apples in total on 2015-05-06 and bought 3 apples on 2011-10-06, so at the date 2015-05-06, the ID 1006 has bought 6 , which is calculated by (3+3), apples in total.
Therefore, my table would look like this:

```
+------+------------+--------------------+
| ID   | orderdate  | accumulative apple |
+------+------------+--------------------+
| 1005 | 2015-05-05 |                  2 |
| 1005 | 2015-05-06 |                  2 | (0 + 2 )
| 1006 | 2011-05-06 |                  3 |
| 1006 | 2011-10-06 |                  6 | (3 + 3)
+------+------------+--------------------+
```

my code is shown as the follows but it turns out to be a very weird result.. would someone please kindly help me with this?

```
select a.ID ID, a.orderdate orderdate, sum(b.apple) apple 
from testfinal3 a 
join testfinal3 b 
on date_format(b. OrderDate, '%Y-%m-%d') >= date_format(a. OrderDate, '%Y-%m-%d') 
group by ID, orderdate 
order by ID, orderdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very nearly there.

Your comparison operator is the wrong way round. You want to join each result on all results that are earlier or equal to the `a.orderdate`, including the `a` row itself using `<=`.

If `orderdate` is a column of type `DATE`, you don't need to pass it through `DATE_FORMAT` before comparison, so you can simplify `DATE_FORMAT(*.orderdate, '%Y-%m-%d')` to `*.orderdate`.

The join will then select **all** records which are earlier than the `a` row. This further needs filtering to only include `b` rows with the same `ID` as the `a` row, using `AND a.ID = b.ID`.

The `ORDER BY` clause is redundant as MySQL orders by the `GROUP BY` clause by default. I've also removed some unnecessary aliasing from your original query.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.orderdate, SUM(b.apple) apple 
FROM testfinal3 a 
JOIN testfinal3 b ON b.orderdate <= a.orderdate AND a.ID = b.ID
GROUP BY a.ID, a.orderdate;
```